# Unir datos columnas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

En el siguiente ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se podrían unir el género en una sola columna?

Por ejemplo :

podcast = 1, Genero = Música, Ficción.

podcast = 2, Genero = Arte, Videojuegos,Política.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede, para eso requieres el comando GROUP_CONCAT y la sintaxis seria la siguiente:

```
SELECT
   idPodcast, GROUP_CONCAT(genero) 
FROM 
   generos 
GROUP BY
   idPodcast
```

Comment: Falta indicar un separador y le puedes poner un alias a la columna de salida, por ejemplo aquí se llamará `generos`...: **`SELECT
   idPodcast, GROUP_CONCAT(genero SEPARATOR ',') generos 
FROM 
   generos 
GROUP BY
   idPodcast`** Por si interesa, también se puede ordenar las columnas si se quiere ([ver aquí](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/))

Comment: Si no le pones un separador, por default te pone la ",". Pero para una persona que apenas comienza, creo que es muy buena idea que utilice el separador para que entienda mejor el concepto

Comment: Correcto. Yo prefiero ponerlo siempre por costumbre y porque además se puede usar combinado con `CONCAT` para obtener grupos y sub-grupos de datos anidados. O porque si hay datos que contienen `,` en las columnas ya se arma el lío... De hecho, por eso nunca uso la `,` como separador. Mi favorito es `|`.