# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de una tabla relacionada 1 a varios en una sola celda en SQL?

Tags: sql

Quisiera saber si es posible tener los datos de una tabla relacionada de 1 a varios en una sola celda en SQL, es decir, el resultado normal sería el siguiente:

`SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN permiso ON usuario.usuario_id = permiso.usuario_id`

| **Usuario** | **Permiso** |
| --- | --- |
| Usuario 1 | Permiso A |
| Usuario 1 | Permiso B |
| Usuario 2 | Permiso C |

Y necesito un resultado así:

| **Usuario** | **Permiso** |
| --- | --- |
| Usuario 1 | Permiso A, Permiso B |
| Usuario 2 | Permiso C |

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Unir datos columnas SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166434/unir-datos-columnas-sql) || Esto asumiendo que estás trabajando con MySQL. No olvides especificar en las etiquetas con qué base de datos estás trabajando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer el siguiente query:

```
SELECT Usuario, GROUP_CONCAT(Permiso SEPARATOR ', ') AS Permiso
FROM (nombre_tabla)
GROUP BY Usuario;
```

De esta manera, la función `GROUP_CONCAT` concatena los múltiples valores de `Permiso` y el `GROUP BY` se encarga de agrupar los valores por usuario.